# Magento 2 UI component category form disable attribute based on system configuration toggle?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am trying to *disable* or *enable* **category attribute** based on *system config* or *helper* value using UI component can I make this directly from here ?

> system config path :- marketplacesetting/category_commissions/enable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="category_commission">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Commission</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="category_commission_percentage">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Commission Percentage</item>
                    <!--<item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="disabled" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.category_commission_percentage.do_we_hide_it</item>-->
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="string">marketplacesetting/category_commissions/enable</item>
                    <item name="scope_info" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="less-than-equals-to" xsi:type="number">99</item>
                        <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-zero-or-greater" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-not-negative-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you can not do that from XML, but you can do by custom component or CLASS.

Comment: can you please provide any example ..? <item name="disabled" class="Omnyfy\Mcm\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DisableCategoryPercentage" xsi:type="boolean"></item>  public function 
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $data) {
                if ($this->_helper->isTransactionFeeEnable() && $this->_helper->isEnable()){
                   return $data['category_commission_percentage']['disabled'] = false;
                } else {
                  return $data['category_commission_percentage']['disabled'] = true;
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by using js with phtml for category add and edit.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category;

class Edit extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

> layout:-Vendor\Modulename\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_category_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="category_form"/>
            <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit" after="-" name="category_percentage" template="catalog/category/edit.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> template:-Vendor\Modulename\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\category\edit.phtml

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('marketplacesetting/category_commissions/enable');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var conf = <?php echo $conf; ?>;
            if (conf != 1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    jQuery("input[name='category_commission_percentage']").prop('disabled', true);
                }, 15000);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```